# Hive: Count non zero characters in substrings of a string

Tags: mysql, hadoop, split, hive

I have a string like the following in the column of a hive external table

```
<id>^<count>^<distinct_count>|<id>^<count>^<distinct_count>|...
```

There are two delimiters. `|` on an entity level and `^` on sub-entity level

I have a metric which is defined by the sum of counts of non-zero `distinct_counts` or `counts`, which means given a string I have check whether the distinct count (or the count - I can check either) is non zero and if it mark a `flag` as 1. Then the metric would be `sum(flags)`. I have to store this metric in an aggregated table in the next step.

Please suggest a way for me to do this in Hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible. Ended up using an external python mapper for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count number of non-zero `count` in a string `s`, it seems to be solved by

```
length(
    regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(s, "[^^|]*\\^0\\^[^^|]*\\|?", ""),
        "[^^|]*\\^[^^|]*\\^[^^|]*\\|?",
        "1"
    )
)
```

First `regexp_replace` removes parts with zero `count`, second `regexp_replace` replaces remaining parts with single symbols (it should not necessarily be `"1"`, any symbol would suffice), and hence `length` returns number of parts with non-zero `count`.